# Accessing the first element of a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called cars. I want to create a new column called 'Brand_name' with just the first element of the brand column but I keep getting error message 'list index out of range'

```
cars = Brand                    Units_sold
       [Toyota]                   87
       [Acura]                    99
       [Toyota, Ford, GMC]        87
       [Kia, Honda]               25
       [Honda]                    109
       [Mercedes, Bugatti]        76
......
```

Here is what I what to achieve

```
cars = Brand                    Units_sold         Brand_name
       [Toyota]                   87               [Toyota]
       [Acura]                    99               [Acura]
       [Ford,Toyota, GMC]         87               [Ford]
       [Kia, Honda]               25               [Kia]
       [Honda]                    109              [Honda]
       [Mercedes, Bugatti]        76               [Mercedes]
....
```

Here is the code I applied

```
cars['Brand_name'] = cars['Brand'].apply(lambda x: x[0])
```

Comment: Use `cars['Brand_name'] = cars['Brand'].str[0]`

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I tried using that code but all it did was give me the first alphabet of the different car brands

Comment: So use `cars['Brand_name'] = cars['Brand'].str. strip('[]').str.split().str[0]`

Comment: thank you so much. That works